# AWS Lamba invoke function with parameters/payload

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I started with AWS Lambda today and I can't succeed in passing a payload to the function. On the server side I try to read all the event data but it is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$client = LambdaClient::factory(array(
'profile' => 'default',
'key' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
'secret' => AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
'region'  => 'eu-west-1'
));

$payload = array('key1' => '1');

$result = $client->invoke(array(
'FunctionName' => 'hello',
'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
'LogType' => 'Tail',
'Payload' => json_encode($payload)
));
```

Returns:

```
Received event: {}
```

Function code on AWS:

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
```

};

Answer (score 2):

In python I send the payload like this:

```
from boto3 import client as botoClient
import json
lambdas = botoClient("lambda")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = lambdas.invoke(FunctionName="myLambdaFunct", InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event));
```

where **event** is a dictionary and, json.dumps serialize **event** to a JSON formatted string